# Javascript HTML5 audio - Dont play sound if already playing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up some HTML audio on my site and I have set an autoplay function after a couple of seconds, however the sound seems to be loading twice? one starts playing straight after the other although, one is a ghost and cannot see a player for it.

How could I go about telling javascript not to start playing sounds if there are already sounds playing?

```
<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 2000)" }>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

The above issue has been solved however I wanted to add a flash fallback for this audio for internet explorer and so added:

```
<div id ="audio">

<script>var readingMusic = false; </script>
<audio controls="controls" loop="loop" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; if (!readingMusic){readingMusic = true;setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 2000)}" }>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3&autoPlay=true" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="400" height="27" quality="best" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</audio>
</div>

<div id="audiohide">
<audio controls="controls" loop="loop" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; if (!readingMusic){readingMusic = true;setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 2000)}" }>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3&autoPlay=true" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="400" height="27" quality="best" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</audio>

</div>
```

But now the flash audio is behaving how the previous audio did obviously the javascript is not affecting the flash embed?

Comment: In which browser do you issue this problem? And is this audio tag the only autoplayable on your webpage?

Comment: Funnily enough all the browsers I have tested Firefox/chrome/IE Im not sure if there is a deeper problem i,e scripts getting loaded twice somewhere etc..? but I wondered if I could just set up a function for the audio not to start playing if it is already playing? I dont mind admitting I'm a newbie to javascript! :(

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with this issue ?

Comment: Mmmmmm first time using jsfiddle not sure if I did it right: http://jsfiddle.net/CNjU7/ but does this help?

Comment: You tried with different audio files? Sounds ok in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah I have tried all formats to mind, Its really frustrating, I think its a jQuery/javascript script getting loaded twice somewhere? But then again, I'm not that clued up.

Comment: Could you attach completely rendered page html source please? Your example works fine without phantom sounds for me on MacOS(Chrome, FF, Safari) and Win7(IE9, Chrome). So it's not an audio tag issue. Futhermore it's restricted for audio element to play itself twice at the same time.

Comment: Strangley the jsfiddle that I created plays the sound fine as it should, but in my site it starts duplicating straight away? Its obviously something wrong on my site.

Comment: Here is the source: http://pastebin.com/Pzx2wDA8

Answer (score 1):

Can't you have a boolean telling the browser if there is already some music playing ?

Example with 2  tags:

```
<script>var readingMusic = false; </script>
<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; if (!readingMusic){readingMusic = true;setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 2000)}" }>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>

<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; if (!readingMusic){readingMusic = true;setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 2000)}" }>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
    <source src="http://www.alanis50.com/Music/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Julien, I salute you! Thank you sooo much, thats been driving me crazy. I guess I learnt something today! :)

Comment: Since you are obviously a very clever person, do you know the best way to implement a flash fallback for this player? For IE?

Comment: I don't know the "best" way since I'm not an expert in HTML5, however this page seems to contain relevant informations for you: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/

Comment: I am kinda back to square one with the flash version of this audio, it is behaving exactly like the HTML 5 one was?? it keeps duplicating, which means its obviously something to do with what 4pcbr was saying below, how can I use the javascript written for the HTML 5 audio to do the same with the flash embed?

Comment: Here is how I have added the flash fallback, but it has the same issue as with the HTML 5 audio which now plays fine? http://pastebin.com/ikrDGpKt

Comment: Even with a different player etc.. http://pastebin.com/bq3RTekW still the same problem, Julian do you have any secret code up your sleeve? Obviously I need to point the same/or similar bit of javascript at the flash object right?

Comment: for flash fallback you need a flash. so you could use [schillmania's](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) with a wonderful API. is the same which is used by soundcloud.com has all useful needed fallbacks in very small swf.

Comment: Hi codelio, its not that the flash fallback is not working, it loads fine, but it is getting load numerous times in my site, it is an AJAX site and its obviously causing issues, but the above code from Julien fixed the audio tag problem but I need to do the same for the flash fallback?

Comment: flash fallback means to decide which flash version is useable if html5 tags are not available, catch and hold ready to play your music files and if possible do not code twice. this is what soundmanager2 does! if you need e very tiny one, there is one version without debugging mode. and yes it can handle AJAX-ed informations.

Comment: Im not sure if that would solve my problem, I think I just need javascript to tell the embedded audio to only play once and not play again if already playing? like what the above javascript achieved with the audio tag, are you able to suggest some code I could try?

Comment: are you using jQuery or something like or native js in this project?

Comment: I am using jQuery in this site, but I think its being load more than once!? Would anyone be willing to login and check things for me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [that's a part](http://pastebin.com/2hEqa8vb) of your [jScript.js](http://alanis50.com/wp-content/themes/studio8/js/jScript.js).

It seems that problem is in this line:

```
location = base + "/#" + current.replace(base, "");
```

You navigating to the new url without leaving current page(if origins are the same and the only difference is in hashes). I recommend you to start playing audio after changing location origin.

So you might place your autoplay logick right after this location changes.